# iOS, Unknown Process, Unknown Crash

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

I have an intermittent crash which my users have been reporting.  I believe it to be a memory issue.  I have finally reproduced it on device, I can not reproduce in the simulator, however, there is no exception, no low memory warning and nothing from iOS that calls any of the methods to exit the application.  It just exits and returns to the main screen.  Doesn't even "terminate" but stays in the suspended app list.

There is an "Unknown" crash log, but I have no idea what it means.  Is there any meaning that can be derived from this log?  My app is the one named SRTS.  The rpages value seems like it might be excessive, but I am not sure.  Any help in interpreting this crash log would be much appreciated.

I am using XCode 4.5.1 and building to iOS SDK 5.1.

```
Incident Identifier: 4695578C-4367-4BE1-860F-94FF8562ECAF
CrashReporter Key:   9de810f246c07ab4704bd4f440fe9a3d0cab9401
Hardware Model:      iPad2,1
OS Version:          iPhone OS 6.0 (10A403)
Kernel Version:      Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Sun Aug 19 00:28:05 PDT 2012; root:xnu-2107.2.33~4/RELEASE_ARM_S5L8940X
Date:                2012-10-18 01:11:40 -0400
Time since snapshot: 103 ms

Free pages:        882
Active pages:      3028
Inactive pages:    1941
Throttled pages:   104533
Purgeable pages:   0
Wired pages:       17730
Largest process:   SRTS

Processes
     Name                    <UUID>                       rpages       recent_max       [reason]          (state)

      MobileMail <bff817c61ce33c85a43ea9a6c98c29f5>         1010             1010         [vm]         (resume) (continuous)
     MobilePhone <3fca241f2a193d0fb8264218d296ea41>          992              992         [vm]         (resume) (continuous)
             kbd <3e7136ddcefc3d77a01499db593466cd>          438              438         [vm]         (daemon)
            tccd <eb5ddcf533663f8d987d67cae6a4c4ea>          179              179         [vm]         (daemon)
            SRTS <66eed1e3358a33a4997bbf88dad284f2>        90334            90334         [vm]         (audio) (frontmost) (resume)
            ptpd <04a56fce67053c57a7979aeea8e5a7ea>          677              677                      (daemon)
       locationd <892cd1c9ffa43c99a82dba197be5f09e>          535              535                      (daemon)
   iaptransportd <f784f30dc09d32078d87b450e8113ef6>          287              287                      (daemon)
           wifid <9472b090746237998cdbb9b34f090d0c>          362              362                      (daemon)
    mediaserverd <80657170daca32c9b8f3a6b1faac43a2>          926              926                      (daemon)
         syslogd <cbef142fa0a839f0885afb693fb169c3>          158              158                      (daemon)
     SpringBoard <27372aae101f3bbc87804edc10314af3>         2031             2031                     
      backboardd <5037235f295b33eda98eb5c72c098858>         5629             5629                      (daemon)
        networkd <0032f46009f53a6c80973fe153d1a588>          206              206                      (daemon)
        BTServer <c92fbd7488e63be99ec9dbd05824f5e5>          347              347                      (daemon)
         configd <4245d73a9e96360399452cf6b8671844>          411              411                      (daemon)
   fairplayd.K93 <47f0ea63619d351db2ef1b21790e89b9>          178              178                      (daemon)
       fseventsd <996cc4ca03793184aea8d781b55bce08>          400              400                      (daemon)
         imagent <1e68080947be352590ce96b7a1d07b2f>          376              376                      (daemon)
   mDNSResponder <3e557693f3073697a58da6d27a827d97>          252              252                      (daemon)
       lockdownd <ba1358c7a8003f1b91af7d5f58dd5bbe>          295              295                      (daemon)
          powerd <2d2ffed5e69638aeba1b92ef124ed861>          197              197                      (daemon)
  UserEventAgent <6edfd8d8dba23187b05772dcdfc94f90>          509              509                      (daemon)
     debugserver <185719f06f1631d4922c652bdd4c8529>            0                0                      (daemon)
       gputoolsd <889065a15ba8372ca533e023c10bd776>            0                0                      (daemon)
       gputoolsd <889065a15ba8372ca533e023c10bd776>            0                0                      (daemon)
       gputoolsd <889065a15ba8372ca533e023c10bd776>            0                0                      (daemon)
springboardservi <ff6f64b3a21a39c9a1793321eefa5304>            0                0                      (daemon)
    syslog_relay <45e9844605d737a08368b5215bb54426>            0                0                      (daemon)
    syslog_relay <45e9844605d737a08368b5215bb54426>            0                0                      (daemon)
filecoordination <fbab576f37a63b56a1039153fc1aa7d8>          169              169                      (daemon)
notification_pro <845b7beebc8538ca9ceef731031983b7>          177              177                      (daemon)
       distnoted <a89af76ec8633ac2bbe99bc2b7964bb0>          177              177                      (daemon)
            apsd <94d8051dd5f5362f82d775bc279ae608>          370              370                      (daemon)
      aggregated <8c3c991dc4153bc38aee1e841864d088>           93               93                      (daemon)
         notifyd <51c0e03da8a93ac8a595442fcaac531f>          163              163                      (daemon)
     ReportCrash <8c32f231b2ed360bb151b2563bcaa363>          234              234                      (daemon)

**End**
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally tracked this down to a memory leak.  I got a clue as to what the leak was by running on an iPad1, which has less memory.  Instead of suspending the app, the iPad1 gave a slightly different crash log, showing that the app was evicted.  This confirmed for me that it was a memory issue.  Enabling Zombie objects and using the simulate memory warning on the simulator helped me to finally track down where the leak was.  So to anyone else who gets an unknown crash log such as this, I would suggest looking for memory leaks first.

Answer (score 1):

Try Enable Zombie Object (on Xcode Product Menu -> Edit Scheme-> select Debug from left side -> On Diagnostics Tab -> Enable Zombie Object) and run on device from XCode. This will give you little more description about the error.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not provide any additional details.